Constructing pointer chains with ctypes
These are simple variable declarations in cpp, how do I do it in Python ctypes?
B *C = (B *) A;
D *E = (D *)(A + sizeof(B));

Assume that B and D are structs and A is uint8_t A[42];. Where do I start from here?
I tried using cast functions but maybe I'm wrong, can you help me?
from ctypes import POINTER, byref, addressof, sizeof, cast

C = cast(byref(A), POINTER(B)).contents
E = cast(addressof(A) + sizeof(B), POINTER(D)).contents


won't A + sizeof(B) result in an address that is offset sizeof(B)*sizeof(B) bytes from A? Or is the expression you are looking for &A[1]?

I don't know actually, I just want to keep it simple. Like I know that for example "uint8_t *A" would result in ctypes Python as POINTER(c_uint8)(). So how do I do it?

I just want somebody to help me explain fully his/her work for me to be more clarified.

you need to properly handle the memory offsets and casting

from ctypes import Structure, POINTER, sizeof, cast, c_uint8
class B(Structure):
fields = [("field1", c_uint8)]
class D(Structure):
fields = [("field1", c_uint8)]
A = (c_uint8 * 42)()
C = cast(A, POINTER(B)).contents
offset = sizeof(B)
E = cast((A + offset), POINTER(D)).contents

Listing [Python.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python.
In short, to:

Dereference a pointer - cts_ptr_var.contents

Reference a variable (to a pointer) - ctypes.pointer(cts_var) (to later pass it as an argument to a function - ctypes.byref(cts_var))

Get its (C) address - ctypes.addressof(cts_var)


Now, regarding your question, a nicer way would be to use (each CTypes type's) from_address (and avoid those pointers).
code00.py:
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ctypes as cts
import sys


I8Arr42 = cts.c_uint8 * 42


class S0(cts.Structure):
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:  # @TODO - cfati: Lame (for demo purposes only)
        _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = (
        ("ui80", cts.c_uint8),
        ("ui81", cts.c_uint8),
        ("ui320", cts.c_uint32),
        ("ui82", cts.c_uint8),
    )

PS0 = cts.POINTER(S0)


class S1(cts.Structure):
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:  # @TODO
        _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = (
        ("ui80", cts.c_uint8),
        ("ui320", cts.c_uint32),
        ("ui81", cts.c_uint8),
    )

PS1 = cts.POINTER(S1)


def main(*argv):
    size0 = cts.sizeof(S0)
    arr = I8Arr42(*range(42))
    #arr = I8Arr42()
    print(arr, hex(cts.addressof(arr)), hex(id(arr)))
    print(f"Initial values: {arr[0]}, {arr[size0]}, {arr[-1]}\n")

    print("FromAddress")

    s00 = S0.from_address(cts.addressof(arr))  # Initialize structure from memory contents at address
    print("First structure:")
    for name, _ in s00. _fields_:
        print(f"  {name}: 0x{getattr(s00, name):02X}")

    s10 = S1.from_address(cts.addressof(arr) + size0)  # Initialize structure from memory contents at address
    print("\nSecond structure:")
    for name, _ in s10. _fields_:
        print(f"  {name}: 0x{getattr(s10, name):02X}")

    s00.ui80 = 100
    s10.ui80 = 101
    print(f"\nModified values: {arr[0]}, {arr[size0]}, {arr[-1]}\n")

    print("\nCast")

    s01 = cts.cast(cts.addressof(arr), PS0).contents
    print("First structure:")
    for name, _ in s01. _fields_:
        print(f"  {name}: 0x{getattr(s01, name):02X}")

    s11 = cts.cast(cts.addressof(arr) + size0, PS1).contents
    print("\nSecond structure:")
    for name, _ in s11. _fields_:
        print(f"  {name}: 0x{getattr(s11, name):02X}")

    s01.ui80 = 200
    s11.ui80 = 201
    print(f"\nModified values: {arr[0]}, {arr[size0]}, {arr[-1]}\n")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(
        "Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(
            " ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
            64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32,
            sys.platform,
        )
    )
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.\n")
    sys.exit(rc)

Output:

[cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackExchange\StackOverflow\q078494178]> sopr.bat
### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###

[prompt]> :: No argument - default (structure) packing
[prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.10_test0\Scripts\python.exe" ./code00.py
Python 3.10.11 (tags/v3.10.11:7d4cc5a, Apr  5 2023, 00:38:17) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32

<__main__.c_ubyte_Array_42 object at 0x000001E9E8C04140> 0x1e9e8fffdb0 0x1e9e8c04140
Initial values: 0, 12, 41

FromAddress
First structure:
  ui80: 0x00
  ui81: 0x01
  ui320: 0x7060504
  ui82: 0x08

Second structure:
  ui80: 0x0C
  ui320: 0x13121110
  ui81: 0x14

Modified values: 100, 101, 41


Cast
First structure:
  ui80: 0x64
  ui81: 0x01
  ui320: 0x7060504
  ui82: 0x08

Second structure:
  ui80: 0x65
  ui320: 0x13121110
  ui81: 0x14

Modified values: 200, 201, 41


Done.


[prompt]> :: Dummy argument - #pragma pack(1)
[prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.10_test0\Scripts\python.exe" ./code00.py dummy
Python 3.10.11 (tags/v3.10.11:7d4cc5a, Apr  5 2023, 00:38:17) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32

<__main__.c_ubyte_Array_42 object at 0x000001A85B484140> 0x1a85b87ff30 0x1a85b484140
Initial values: 0, 7, 41

FromAddress
First structure:
  ui80: 0x00
  ui81: 0x01
  ui320: 0x5040302
  ui82: 0x06

Second structure:
  ui80: 0x07
  ui320: 0xB0A0908
  ui81: 0x0C

Modified values: 100, 101, 41


Cast
First structure:
  ui80: 0x64
  ui81: 0x01
  ui320: 0x5040302
  ui82: 0x06

Second structure:
  ui80: 0x65
  ui320: 0xB0A0908
  ui81: 0x0C

Modified values: 200, 201, 41


Done.


For future tasks, you might want to check [SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer) for a common pitfall when working with CTypes (calling functions).

Does sombody have another solution? I can accept this, but I need a deeper explanation, specificaly related to asterisk and ampersands and how they should affect what ctypes Python equivalent looks like.

If you set it to arr = I8Arr48(), would your entire code still work? I mean the uint8_t A[42] is empty list at the moment and the goal is to fill it up using this structs and setting up the specific values for it. Can you modify your code just like what I said? I'll Accept this answer if you can do it.

Why wouldn't it work? The array would then be 0ed. I initialized it this way to ilustrate that structure members are initialized with the array contents (it would be useless for a 0ed array).

I added the code that modifies the structure members and it's visible in the array.

It seems you want to build two structures from byte data.  You can use .from_buffer_copy() to create structures from any data, and .from_buffer() to create structures from mutable data where the structures will follow changes to the data.
Example:
import ctypes as ct

# helper function for __repr__ implementations
def hexlist(arr):
    return '[' + ', '.join([hex(n) for n in arr]) + ']'

# Example structure (17 bytes)
class B(ct.Structure):
    _pack_ = 1  # Ensure no structure padding
    _fields_ = (('a', ct.c_int * 4),
                ('b', ct.c_ubyte))

    # Define for class instances to be printable
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'B(a={hexlist(self.a)}, b={self.b:#x})'

# Example structure (25 bytes)
class D(ct.Structure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = (('a', ct.c_ubyte),
                ('b', ct.c_int * 6))

    # Define for class instances to be printable
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'D(a={self.a:#x}, b={hexlist(self.b)})'

# 17 + 25 = 42
A = bytes(range(42))  # values 0-41, immutable, use from_buffer_copy

C = B.from_buffer_copy(A)
E = D.from_buffer_copy(A, ct.sizeof(B))  # 2nd parameter is offset to copy from

print(C)
print(E)

A = bytearray(range(42))  # values 0-41, mutable, use either buffer method.

C = B.from_buffer(A)
E = D.from_buffer(A, ct.sizeof(B))  # 2nd parameter is offset

# Changes to A will follow in C and E
A[ct.sizeof(B) - 1] = 0xAA  # byte offset of C.b member.
A[ct.sizeof(B)] = 0x99  # byte offset of E.a member.
print(C)  # note b member value
print(E)  # note a member value

Output:
B(a=[0x3020100, 0x7060504, 0xb0a0908, 0xf0e0d0c], b=0x10)
D(a=0x11, b=[0x15141312, 0x19181716, 0x1d1c1b1a, 0x21201f1e, 0x25242322, 0x29282726])
B(a=[0x3020100, 0x7060504, 0xb0a0908, 0xf0e0d0c], b=0xaa)
D(a=0x99, b=[0x15141312, 0x19181716, 0x1d1c1b1a, 0x21201f1e, 0x25242322, 0x29282726])

